# How can I let my bot in discord.py respond to specific users?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I let my bot in discord.py respond to specific users? I've tried:

`if ctx.message.author.id == [740936250608844890, 483686172221243402]:`

and tried to use config.yml file, as this:

`if ctx.message.author.id == config['Whitelist']:`

and the config file has this:

`Whitelist: [483686172221243402, 740936250608844890]`

**Note:** I want it to be list or something like that so I can add new users anytime easily.

Comment: You can put all the users in a text file perhaps. Or maybe a list at top of the code which this if statement can access.

Comment: Or maybe create a role and the bot only responds to users with that role. There are many ways you can solve this issue.

Comment: @Goion I tried to make a list on config.yml and didn't work:(

Comment: Where did I say modify `config.yml`? I have no idea what you are doing, I can't help you. I gave you several options. Try them all out.

Comment: @Goion how can i use text file, can you type what should i type in the text file? and how to use it in main.py?

Comment: Also you are comparing a id to list which makes no sense. You should be checking `if ctx.message.author.id in config['Whitelist']:`

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, there are a lot of ways of achieving what you want. In the way you chose, the mistake is in the `==` operator, which should be replaced by `in`.

It should look like this:

```
if ctx.message.author.id in [740936250608844890, 483686172221243402]:
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to store ids in a separate file, you could do the following:

```
with open("ids.txt") as ids_file: # In 'ids.txt' write one id per line
    if srt(ctx.message.author.id) in ids_file.read():
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I see that you want this command to only users with these IDs. So this is pretty easy, you just need to use for loops to iterate through the list and then check for that.

Step by Step let's make you understand.

1. Create the list with the user IDs:
   This right here is the list of those users which can use the command and no one else.

```
special_users = [740936250608844890, 483686172221243402]
```

2. Creating a `for` loop that iterates over the list:
   So now we will write a for loop that will provide us the iteration through which we will go through the user IDs one by one and return the values from it.

```
for user in special_users:
    # Step 3 for code
```

3. Adding if statement inside for loop:
   Now we will add an `if` statement that will use the `user` we defined in the loop and check for the ID.

```
if message.author.id == user:
   # Perform the function you want to.
   # Write the code you want here.
```

---

We are done. It was mostly that simple, and not if I combine all those pieces it would be this:

```
special_users = [740936250608844890, 483686172221243402]
for user in special_users:
    if message.author.id == user:
       # Perform the function you want to.
       # Write the code you want here.
```

---

Hope you understand and I could help. Still get any problem? Comment down below and let me know.

Thank You! :D